# Getting currently unacknowledged consumer messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, sigterm

I'm trying to gracefully shutdown a process that is consuming messages off RabbitMQ. I know that I can use `Channel.cancel` to stop RabbitMQ from sending any new messages to the process, but I need to deal with any pending, unacknowledged messages as well. I could just call `Channel.nackAll` and re-queue all of them, but it would be better if I could wait till all of the pending messages - messages that were consumed, but not yet acked/nacked - were done.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Cancel the consumer
- Ack the messages you are currently "working" on when the work is done
- When the above is done, close channels and connections. Anything that is un-acked will be re-enqueued by RabbitMQ.

Comment: How would I know that all pending work is done? Is there some way to hook into when that happens?

Comment: Your application is doing work with each message. That is what I mean by "pending work".

Comment: Yes, but how would I be able to tell when all pending work is done? AFAIK there is no "get count of currently consumed, but not yet acked messages" method in RabbitMQ.

I could track incoming/processed messages manually in code, but it seems like it could be a bit brittle (one of the messages gets skipped for some reason and the count is off for the entire duration of the process).

Comment: It is up to your application to keep track. You should be setting a QoS / prefetch value so that you know the maximum count of un-acked messages RabbitMQ will allow on your consumer's channel.

Comment: I guess that answers my question - RabbitMQ offers no way to get (at least the count of) currently received but not yet acked/nacked messages.